# How to enable Ctrl + Mouse Wheel for horizontal scrolling on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, scrolling, mouse-wheel

Usually, scrolling horizontally can be done on Windows machines with Ctrl + mouse wheel. Now, Firefox uses this to increase/decrease page size (which I hardly ever use).

Is there a way to tell FF to use Ctrl + mouse wheel for horizontal scrolling?

I looked at `about:config` and there are some options `mousewheel. ...`, but unfortunately I don't know, what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Mozilla Knowledgebase article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries#Mousewheel.) covers the scrollwheel. I don't think this behavior can be achieved without an extension.   I haven't tried it but you can try setting the action to -1 and seeing if the default Windows behavior takes over.

```
mousewheel.withcontrolkey.action -1
```

Comment: Hm. -1 renders Ctrl + mouse wheel inactive, i.e., nothing happens anymore. As mentioned in the comment to the other answer, mousewheel.horizscroll.* doesn't be of any help either. Thanks for the try!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the fix suggested [here](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/web/firefox-scrolling-fix.html), but it will make you scroll horizontally just using the mousewheel on its own (without the Ctrl key). The following lines need to be set to "1":

```
mousewheel.horizscroll.withnokey.action - Set this to '1'
mousewheel.horizscroll.withnokey.numlines - Set this to '1'
```

Comment: Looks like by default (I'm using FF v3.5.2), horizontal scrolling through the mousewheel alone works *by default* (tested on http://www.thehorizontalway.com/). Changing the values I've mentioned apparently has no effect.

Comment: The problem seems to be, that mousewheel.horizscroll.* is triggered only, if you have one of those fancy gamers' mice.